# no new lines in lyx output from the latex code insertion

Tags: math-mode, lyx, line-breaking

```
      \begin{widetext}
        \begin{displaymath}
        a+b=c;\\
d+e = f;\\
e+m = n;\\
        \end{displaymath}
        \end{widetext}
```

I am using the above code as an inserted Tex Code in Lyx but I do not get any new lines whether I use \\ or \newline. How do I correct this ?

Comment: You can't have linebreak with display math. Use `align*`,  or `gather*` if you don't want alignment points.

Comment: Why are you inserting the LaTeX code rather than using the LyX math editor?

Comment: Because I did not know how to use the widetext in lyx. So I directly put the code there.

Comment: Indeed LyX does not support `widetext` environment. However because your math is inside of it, you could have ERT `\begin{widetext}` and then normal LyX math or align or however you choose and then afterwards ERT `\end{widetext}`. It just comes down to a matter of preference though.

Comment: @scottkosty Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think Bernard actually answered the question.

Comment: @scottkosty You both did in my opinion, in different ways. (Well, you could say that Bernard answered the question as it's written, while you answered the unstated, underlying question.)

Comment: @Bernard Would you like to answer?

Comment: `@Torbjøn: OK. Btw, what does `ERT` stand for?

Comment: @Bernard Sadly "Evil Red Text" to most, although I prefer "Embedded Raw TeX". See http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ERT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have linebreaks within display math. Use align*, or gather* if you don't want alignment points.

To have an alignment on the `=` sign, mark it with an ampersand:

```
\begin{widetext}
  \begin{align*}
     a+b& =c;\\
    d+e &= f;\\
    e+m &= n;\\
  \end{align*}
\end{widetext}
```

Note that you may have several alignment points. If you want to have n groups of equations with an alignment, you need `2n–1` ampersands. Example:

```
\begin{widetext}
  \begin{align}
    a+b &= c; & a'+b'&= c'\\
    d+e &= f; & d'+e' &= f'\\
    e+m &= n; & e'+m' &= n'\\
  \end{align}
\end{widetext}
```

To have a succession of centred equations, use the `gather*` environment:

```
\begin{widetext}
  \begin{gather*}
     a+b =c;\\
    d+e = f;\\
    e+m = n;\\
  \end{gather*}
\end{widetext}
```